# How can I search for messages (embeds) with a particular 'author' through DiscordSocketClient?

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I'm in the process of building a new Discord bot (of course), and I've been working on the Twitter integration using [Tweetinvi](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi). I've got most of the Twitter streaming bits working normally (at least, as far as I can tell in my simplified testing), but I wanted to have the bot modify/delete posts in Discord if the Tweet is subsequently deleted. Tweetinvi has a `TweetDeleted` event that I can use to detect this as a part of my stream, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to find the post in Discord.

What I'd *like* to do is "simply":

1. Search for posts (embeds) from the author (defined by the original Tweet)
2. Find the post with a matching `.Url` value in the embed
3. Replace that post with a message like "**`THIS TWEET WAS DELETED`**".

The problem I'm running into, however, is I can't seem to find a way to do "step 1" - search for and return any posts from the specified author. The only option I've found so far is the `GetMessagesAsync` method, but that doesn't seem to have a way to filter the results. Plus, with the "soft limit" of 100 messages, I worry that I could still not find the message I'm looking to delete.

I post the embeds using the `DiscordSocketClient` object in my class like this:

```vb
Me.A1FDiscordClient.GetGuild(Server.ID).GetTextChannel(PostingChannel).SendMessageAsync(MessageText.Trim, False, TweetBuilder.Build)
```

I had started working on something similar for the deletion/modification, but I think I'm simply spinning my wheels at this point:

```vb
Dim Messages = Me.A1FDiscordClient.GetGuild(Server.ID).GetTextChannel(PostingChannel).GetMessagesAsync(100)
```

I'm probably being dense and/or completely overlooking something, but I'm not even sure what to do with this once I have it. I was looking at using the `.Select(Of TResult)`, but I think I've just gotten myself too twisted. I don't necessarily need a whole solution, but I could really use someone giving me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: **1** Your only option to retrieve messages is GetMessagesAsync()... discord does not provide a search endpoint to get specific messages. **2** The limit is not 100, that's the default, you can change it to anything you wish (still not the best approach). ... **Ideally** you'd have to setup your own message cache that links a message id to a twitter post id or whatever identifier you wish to use. When the twitter post changes, check your cache for the post and it's corresponding message id.

Comment: Thank you, @Anu6is - It sounds like this should be posted as an answer. I guess my ***best*** option would probably be to store these ID's in a SQLite database, or something. That wouldn't be too difficult to add to the bot, although I was kinda hoping to avoid the addition of *yet another* file and dependency in my application. Still, I might be able to use it for some other purpose in my bot (maybe I'll work on a trivia thing, or something).

Comment: In reference to the "*soft* limit" of 100 I mentioned, when I was trying to find a way to do this, many posts in various places suggested that returning more than 100 caused "unusual behavior". I'm already in new territory here, so I want to avoid as many potential problems as possible.

Comment: Not sure why they'd say that. Besides a delay when retrieving a large amount, which should be expected, there are no potential problems. The library handles any possible rate limit scenarios that would arise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Discord does not provide an endpoints for Bots to search/filter on specific criteria. The only way to retrieve messages is to use the `GetMessagesAsync()` method
2. The limit for `GetMessagesAsync()` is technically `Int32.MaxValue`. The 100 that you see is simply the default. This is because Discord will return in chunks; 100 messages at a time. For example if you set the limit to 1000, you will get 10 chunks of 100.
3. Possible issues with retrieving a large number of messages? The main issue would be the length of time taken to retrieve the messages, which could block the gateway unless offload the process to its own task.

A possible solution would be to implement your own system for linking and storing twitter posts to discord posts. Could be as simple as a dictionary of Twitter post id and discord post id which would allow you to easily find the message id related to a given twitter post.